# Is $\mathbb F_p[[x]]$ a projective $\mathbb Z_p[[x]]$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb Z_p$ be the ring of $p$-adic integers and consider the power series ring $\mathbb Z_p[[x]]$.

Let us consider the $\mathbb Z_p[[x]]$-module $\mathbb F_p[[x]]$, where $\mathbb F_p \cong \mathbb Z_p/p \mathbb Z_p$.

> Is $\mathbb F_p[[x]]$ a projective $\mathbb Z_p[[x]]$-module ?

---

I think since $\mathbb F_p$ has torsion, it is not flat module and hence can not be projective.

Am I right ?

Comment: You are correct. Projective modules are flat.

Comment: @Mohan, thank you